# Resetting rpm fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, rpm, update

Before I start let me say that I searched around for this, I wouldn't be here otherwise

**The problem**

While trying to upgrade fedora I used this command

```
rpm -Uhv ftp://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/releases/12/Fedora/i386/os/Packages/fedora-release-12-1.noarch.rpm
```

to switch repos to install, only to find out later that I don't have wget installed (live version running)
I then proceeded with yum install but any yum install I tried returns this:

```
totem-gstreamer-2.24.3-3.fc10.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: totem = 2.24.3 is needed by package totem-gstreamer-2.24.3-3.fc10.i386 (installed)
pulseaudio-core-libs-0.9.14-3.fc10.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libltdl.so.3 is needed by package pulseaudio-core-libs-0.9.14-3.fc10.i386 (installed)
preupgrade-1.1.2-1.fc10.noarch from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.5 is needed by package preupgrade-1.1.2-1.fc10.noarch (installed)
sos-1.8-17.fc10.noarch from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.5 is needed by package sos-1.8-17.fc10.noarch (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.5 is needed by package preupgrade-1.1.2-1.fc10.noarch (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: totem = 2.24.3 is needed by package totem-gstreamer-2.24.3-3.fc10.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: libltdl.so.3 is needed by package pulseaudio-core-libs-0.9.14-3.fc10.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.5 is needed by package sos-1.8-17.fc10.noarch (installed)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

**What I've tried so far**

```
curl "http://pgp.mit.edu:11371/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x855099B249C8885A" | rpm --import --verbose -rpm -Uvh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm rpm -Uvh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-stable.noarch.rpm
rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db
rpm --rebuilddb
```

None seem to do anything, how can I restore the default rpm and get on with work?
I don't have GUI access to this sytem, only command line, but downtime is not an issue

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading Fedora can be a pain.  The [Fedora yum upgrade](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/YumUpgradeFaq) page walks you through all the options, including resolution of dependency problems.

You shouldn't need anything from rpmfusion to do the basic upgrade; I would disable the rpmfusion repository until you are on Fedora 12.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to jump from Fedora 10 to Fedora 12.
I'm not sure such an upgrade is tested.
To restore yum I would reinstall the Fedora 10 release rpm

```
rpm -Uvh --oldpackage http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/releases/11/Fedora/i386/os/Packages/fedora-release-11-1.noarch.rpm
```

And try to do the upgrade with preupgrade

```
yum install preupgrade
```

But you need free space on your disk